# IndexError: list index out of range in " labels += [i.split('/')[-2]] "

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition

I'm new to TensorFlow and python. I'm trying to run and learn "the Speech Recognition using Keras" in https://www.kaggle.com/sunyuanxi/speech-recognition-keras and I have a problem with this part of the code below and cant debug the error.
I really need you to help me.
thank you

```
labels = []
for i in glob('C:\\Users\\SAHAR\\conda_code\\tamrin_deep_speech\\train\\audio\\*\\*.wav'):
    print("a")
    labels += [i.split('/')[-2]]
    print("b")
labels = np.unique(np.array(labels), return_counts=True)

d = {}
for i in range(len(labels[0])):
    d[labels[0][i]] = labels[1][i]
print(d)
```

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ecc5faf1bf75> in <module>
      2 for i in glob('C:\\Users\\SAHAR\\conda_code\\tamrin_deep_speech\\train\\audio\\*\\*.wav'):
      3     print("a")
----> 4     labels += [i.split('/')[-2]]
      5     print("b")
      6 labels = np.unique(np.array(labels), return_counts=True)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image: the result in the picture]

[image: the input data]

[the source of the code](https://www.kaggle.com/sunyuanxi/speech-recognition-keras)

Comment: It's probably because your `.split()` call returned an array of size one in the case of one element, hence making `[-2]` an index out of range.

Comment: Note that for path operations, the standard library os.path and pathlib are generally superior to manual string manipulation. In this case, you are using the wrong path separator. / is the separator for UNIX, \ for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, the path separator is '\' not '/'.
Try to use:

```
labels += [i.split('\\')[-2]]
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are splitting the string on '/'. Just check whether your list after split contain elements. It looks like in your case, some list after split are empty